# Extracting specific MS word tables into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, extract

I have a report that is imported into word. It has fields (which remain the same for each report), each in their own table on the left that correspond to values (which change per report) on the right. The objective is to place these corresponding values to excel in a single row. The problem I am having is identifying the field tables and than moving the cursor to the right and selecting the value in the corresponding table. Right now I am manipulating another script which allows the user to select a cell, run the script, choose the file, locates the field table, selects the table to the right, copies value into excel. All tables are 1x1 cells, due to how the software imports into word.

```
Sub GrabUsage()
Dim FName As String, FD As FileDialog
Dim WApp As Object, WDoc As Object, WDR As Object
Dim ExR As Range
Dim TableNo As Long

Set ExR = Selection ' current location in Excel Sheet

'let's select the WORD doc
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
FD.Show
If FD.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    FName = FD.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

 ' open Word application and load doc
Set WApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
' WApp.Visible = True
Set WDoc = WApp.Documents.Open(FName)
TableNo = WDoc.tables.Count

' Find field table on left side
WApp.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Unique Furniture Produced"

' move cursor to corresponding value table on right side
WApp.Selection.Move Unit:=TableNo, Count:=1

' I need this part to select the tables value
'WApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=2, Count:=1, Extend:=1

' grab and put into excel
Set WDR = WApp.Selection
ExR(1, 1) = WDR ' place at Excel cursor

WDoc.Close
WApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Prints a square symbol into the selected excel cell, while it's supposed to print 2 for the example report I am using. We want to keep a running log of our production and being able to extract the data from the imported word reports into excel with the use of VBA would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a different method:

```
Sub ReportImport()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next



wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    resultRow = lastrow - 2

    tableStart = 1
    With .tables(tableStart)
        Cells(resultRow, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(3, 3).Range.Text)  'sheets
        Cells(resultRow, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(11, 3).Range.Text) 'gross sa
        Cells(resultRow, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(6, 3).Range.Text)  'gross $
        Cells(resultRow, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(4, 4).Range.Text)  'yield different call from column then rest
        Cells(resultRow, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(12, 3).Range.Text) 'net sa
        Cells(resultRow, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(7, 3).Range.Text)  'net $
        Cells(resultRow, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(8, 3).Range.Text)  'scrap $
        Cells(resultRow, 10) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(10, 3).Range.Text) 'cut in.

    End With

End With

End Sub
```